# Can I embed data files in an Rmarkdown document knitted to a pdf?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

At present I compile to HTML which lets me embed a csv of my data with a function call (see below). I'm trying to get this functionality working when I knit to PDF as well but can't for the life of me work out how this can be accomplished. There are [methods to embed files in Latex documents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19025/embed-link-to-an-embedded-file) but I'm not sure how to bridge this into an Rmarkdown document and have it embed data with a simple function call as I do at the moment. Any ideas?

```
 embed_data= function(x, filename = "file.csv", label = "    Get data    "){

  if(!isTRUE(getOption('knitr.in.progress'))){
    cat('Will Embed Data When Knitting')
    return('') 
  } else {

    x <- data.frame(x)
    for(col in names(x))  {
      x[,col] <- str_replace_all(x[,col], '\n', ' ')
      }

    # Create encoded Base64 datastream 
    encode_data= function(x){
      write.csv(x, file = "./file.csv")
      enc = sprintf('data:text/csv;base64,%s', openssl::base64_encode(paste0(readLines("./file.csv"), collapse = "\n")) )
      unlink("./file.csv")
      return(enc)
    }

    # String result ready to be placed in rmarkdown
    cat('    \n', paste0("<a download='", filename, "' href=", encode_data(x), ">", label, "</a>",'    \n'))    
  }
}
```